# Send some data to server without REST in JS

Tags: javascript, http

As far as i understand all what REST do is standartize a data sended to server by adding some headers. For example REST request can generate a line of bytes like so: `POST /qwe HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1 Connection: keep-alive` and finish it with some user input.

Now im just playing with writing my own JS server and here is my question: is there a way in JS to send some data(bytes) without this REST addings like headers/method and will it work for browsers and HTTP protocol itself?

For example instead of sending `POST /qwe HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1 Connection: keep-alive MY DATA OVER THERE!!!` just send `MY DATA OVER THERE!!!` so my server can read only user data without everything else.

Iv tried to google and end up that `XMLhttpRequest` and `fetch` both require some CRUD method to be specified and adding some headers in request anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create and use your own protocol as an alternative to HTTP?  For what purpose?

Comment: @David im not sure what im doind but im just want to get rid from all this headers and CRUD methods cos here is no use in them for me in my current blank project. Just want to try my own data patterns.

Comment: "I'm not sure" isn't really a great place to start.  *Creating your own protocol* generally involves considerable work and a solid understanding of communication technologies and protocol layers.  What's the *actual problem* you're trying to solve?  What is your application doing that specifically requires *not* using HTTP?  (As an aside... What you're describing is HTTP, not REST.)

Comment: @David ok, my target is to get rid from obscured data (headers, method, path) that trails with request itself and then catching by my server if its even possible without breaking HTTP protocol.

Comment: So you're not solving an actual problem, you just want to create and use your own alternative protocol to HTTP as an idle curiosity and/or academic exercise?  In that case what you have ahead of you is a lot of research and testing.  And potentially writing your own browser, browser extension, or some other client since browsers *generally* rely on HTTP.  And more to the point, the exercise is wholly outside the scope of what Stack Overflow can do for you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David well thats actually was my question: can i send a data(bytes) by JS without mandatory methods and headers. Simple yes or no would be enough. Some link to when i can read about technicall details of HTTP and why methods are required would be a great addition.

Comment: *"can i send a data(bytes) by JS without mandatory methods and headers"* - Depending on what you mean by "mandatory methods and headers", yes.  Though with considerable work.  For example, there are NodeJS libraries which use different functionality under the hood to communicate with different systems/protocols.  (Database drivers, for example.)  So, yes, you *can* create your own application layer protocol.  Think of it this way... The fact that application protocols *exist* suggests that it is indeed possible to create them.

Comment: @David sure thing. My single concern was that this CRUD methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and some headers (Accept, Origin etc) is fully cosmetical and actually do not required for HTTP protocol to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests:

- Need to specify the method
- Need to specify the Host as a header (in HTTP 1.1. and newer)
- Will include some other request headers automatically when make using JS from a browser

This has **nothing to do with REST**. It's just how HTTP works.

---

A non-HTTP protocol could avoid having that. JavaScript in a browser has no mechanisms that allow making non HTTP requests.

---

You might want to research [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) which allows two way communication over a single connection … but that is a bootstrapped by HTTP so doesn't really fulfil your requirement.

Comment: So without sending information by my server about what method do i choose as just a regular unparsed row of bytes HTTP cannot work? Or its needed for some lower-level mechanisms that then throwed into my higher JS reciever as a row of bytes?

Comment: What? If you send "a regular unparsed row of bytes" then it isn't HTTP (and I don't think you understand what the word "parsed" means).

Comment: Ok i guess i dont understand HTTP. From my perspective as server programmer it looks like im getting some unnecessary data that can be easily ommited without any lose. Like the only thing what REST methods changes is what i will get as the first word in recieved bytes and thats it. Feels pretty useless and purely cosmetic.

Comment: Again: The HTTP method is HTTP, not REST (and they have significant differences in meaning, especially around if a request can be considered *safe* or *idempotent*). You really should read the HTTP specification before trying to violate it.

Comment: But why CRUD methods is described as part of REST pattern system?

Comment: Shockingly, creating, reading, updating, and deleting bits of data is a thing lots of people want to do in lots of different situations and tools and protocols evolve to make those operations easy.

Comment: Like optimizing request itself for better timings and bytes consumption? If its just cosmetical for "making peoples life easier" then i dont need that. That was my whole question.

Comment: Ignoring everything I've said and restating what you want will not change the facts I've already given you.

Comment: Ok im very confused. You literally said that methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) "is what people often want to do" so no technical meaning behind them and thats confuse me becouse my actual question was "can i send a request without this methods?". But if its at the same time cosmetic AND this cosmetic thing is mandatory for HTTP protocol - then its a different story.

Comment: You continue to ignore what I said and make me repeat myself. I said, in the very first bullet point in my answer, that an HTTP request must include a method. I have also said, in earlier comments, that methods are not cosmetic. End of conversation.

Answer (score 0):

> For example instead of sending `POST /qwe HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1 Connection: keep-alive MY DATA OVER THERE!!!` just send `MY DATA OVER THERE!!!` so my server can read only user data without everything else.

I suspect you're misunderstanding what a request *is*, on a fundamental level. Without `POST` (the method), `/qwe` (the path), `HTTP/1.1` (the protocol) and `127.0.0.1` (the address) there is no way for your computer to know where and how to send the data. These are necessary if you want to communicate with a server, and removing them will mean your code no longer works.

You're working with very low-level data here, which is probably not what you actually want to be doing. There are some packages which will let you ignore the how and what of the request, and focus on just the data inside it. [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) might be a good place to start. You can set up a simple express server to handle requests on specific paths, and reply with data that your frontend can then use.

A REST API is a high-level concept and largely unrelated to what you're asking about.

Comment: No matter what method im using my server always recieving just a line of bytes with this method being in headers. Maybe if all this unneccessery information (for me) is required for protocol to function on some lower level - then its understandable.

Comment: 'Maybe if all this unneccessery information (for me) is required for protocol to function on some lower level' yes, exactly this. What server software are you running? I suspect that changing that will help, a lot of server-side packages will let you ignore all the protocol stuff and just work with the data.

Comment: Im using JS V8 engine as server. Deno to be more accurate. And its actually my own will to understand all this data flow empirically and write my own server code without additional modules. Thats when i found this CRUD methods from REST patterns and alot of headers that looks absolutely unnecessary for me. But i guess its somehow relevant for HTTP protocol itself if i cannot work without them.